# Plotting circle diagram with rotary arrow

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, visualization

This is a diagram I clipped from a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1352231009008838).

http://i11.tietuku.com/e1c71d1b84b37a51.png

I can plot the circle and the straight arrow, but how to plot the rotary arrow in specific angle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw a circle and a rotary arrow in matplotlib using sine/cosine, [Arc](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Arc) and [arrow](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=arrow#matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow):

```
import math
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes()
x0, y0 = 0.5, 0.5
radius = 0.4
angle = 135
angle_rad = angle * math.pi / 180  # degrees to radians
# Draw circle
circle = plt.Circle((x0,y0), radius, color='red', fill=False)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle)
# Draw radius arrow
head_length = 0.05
ax.arrow(x0, y0,
         (radius - head_length) * math.cos(angle_rad),
         (radius - head_length) * math.sin(angle_rad),
         head_width=0.05, head_length=head_length, fc='k', ec='k')
# Draw arc with arrow.
arc_radius = radius / 4
arc = Arc((x0, y0),
          arc_radius*2, arc_radius*2,  # ellipse width and height
          theta1=0, theta2=angle, linestyle='dashed')
ax.add_patch(arc)
arc_arrow_length = 0.03
arc_arrow_dx = arc_arrow_length * math.cos(angle_rad + math.pi / 2)
arc_arrow_dy = arc_arrow_length * math.sin(angle_rad + math.pi / 2)
ax.arrow(
    x0 + arc_radius * math.cos(angle_rad) - arc_arrow_dx,
    y0 + arc_radius * math.sin(angle_rad) - arc_arrow_dy,
    # We want to define a vector,
    # but we don't want to draw any line besides arrow head,
    # so we make arrow "body" unnoticeable.
    arc_arrow_dx * 0.000001,
    arc_arrow_dy * 0.000001,
    head_width=0.01,
    head_length=0.03,
    color='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result]

Please note that this solution is not the cleanest, there is probably a better way to draw an arc and an arrow at once.

You may want to try [FancyArrowPatch](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=fancyarrowpatch#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch) to draw a nice arrow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's helpful. But what I'm trying to do is plotting the rotary arrow in imaginary line ' -- '.

Comment: @HanZhengzu This problem is surprisingly difficult. I added a solution, but it feels like a hack. Couldn't find a proper way to end an arc with an arrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

Using plt.annotate, in the arrowprops parameter you can pass in a connectionstyle, which will define the curvature of the line you draw. Here's [an example](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#annotate-some-points) from the SciPy documentation. After that, all you need to do is set your linestyle and determine your beginning and ending points for each diagram.